# How to stop white lines on edge of background in sprite kit Xcode?

Tags: ios, background, sprite-kit

This is my code for a scrolling background:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            bg1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"nightbackground"];
            bg1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
            bg1.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
            [bg1 setScale:0.5];
            [self addChild:bg1];

            bg2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"nightbackground"];
            bg2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
            bg2.position = CGPointMake(bg1.size.width-1, 0);
            [bg2 setScale:0.5];
            [self addChild:bg2];
        }
```

Now when the new repeated image comes in, you can see where the new image starts, there is a white line. Is their a way of getting rid of it or overlapping the two so you don't see the start of it?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            _bg =
            [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"nightbackground"];
            _bg.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            _bg.position = CGPointMake(i * _ground.size.width, 0);
            _bg.name = @"bg";
            _bg.zPosition = 10;


            [self addChild:_bg];
        }
```

I would have tried this solution, you make the anchorpoint the middle of the sprite and use the for-loop-value to place them out. You only need one **addchild**